# Running a query with Classic ASP Code from Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, asp-classic

I am connecting with the following ASP code to Oracle Database.

```
Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.Open "Provider=MSDAORA;
                       Data Source=şemam;
                       User Id=kadi;
                       Password=sifre;"
aranan = Request("aranan")

Set objRs = objConn.Execute("Sql Komut")
if objRs.BOF and objRs.eof then
  response.end
end if
```

I can be query on a single table.  But when I run a SQL query to join to more than one table, I receive the following error:

> "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle" Hresult:
>   0x80004005 Description: "Data type is not supported

Comment: What is "sql komut" supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

"Sql Komut" must be a valid SQL query.

For example (assuming theres a table called CUSTOMER in the database):

```
Set objRs = objConn.Execute("SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER")
```

Also, in your code, theres no need to check for both BOF and EOF. Only one is enough to check if a given recordset is empty. Try this:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table"
Set objRs = objConn.Execute(strSQL)
if objRs.eof then
  response.end
end if
```

Comment: Checking for only EOF will work most of the time.  But best practice is to check for both BOF and EOF.

Comment: "most of the time"? In my 10+ years of professional experience with classic ASP, ive never seen this failing once. Right after fetching results from a connection, EOF is true *if and only if* the recordset has no rows. Care to show an example where it wouldnt?